# weblate docker on aws ec2 lost ssh access when ec2 is recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, weblate

I run weblate docker image on ec2. When the ec2 is destroyed in response of unhealthy check of ALB, I lost ssh key used to connect to my VCS (bitbucket).
It seems weblate stores it's private key inside a container's folder... obviously the container can be stoped and replaced as well as ec2.

Can I store ssh key in a persistent store?

Answer (score -1):

Weblate stores SSH key in the data volume which is supposed to be configured as persistent, see https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/install/docker.html#docker-container-volumes for more details.

Comment: Ok. So is not recommended recreate instance